# Hive regexp_replace

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

my use case is the follow:

```
String text_string: "text1:message1,text3:message3,text2:message,..."

select regexp_replace(text_string, '[^:]*:([^,]*(,|$))', '$1')

Correct output: message1,message3,message2,...
```

The pattern work, but the problem is that if there is a character ":" o "," in the message the replace doesn't work.

So I tried to use "::" and ",," characters as a separators in the string

```
String text_string: "text1::message1,,text3::message3,,text2::message2,..."

select regexp_replace(text_string, '[^::]*::([^,,]*(,,|$))', '$1')

Correct output: message1,,message3,,message2,,...
```

but also in this case, if there is one ":" or "," character in the string (in the text or in the message) the replace command doesn't work.

How should the regular expression be modified to work?

Answer (score 0):

Delimiters cannot be characters that are likely to be in the data.  Since you have control over it, use pipes '`|`' or tildes '`~`' maybe.  Only you can come up with the right characters by analyzing the data.

If you can't do that, then you'll need to put quotes around the data that contains the delimiter character and come up with a way to deal with that.